# Is a primary key necessary to replicate inserts using pglogical?

Tags: postgresql, replication, pglogical

I tried to setup a simple master > slave replication using pglogical.
The [pglogical docs](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/pglogical-docs/) mention that one needs a primary key for replicating updates and deletes. Since I don't need neither one, I set up a replication set at the provider as follows:

```
SELECT pglogical.create_replication_set(
set_name := 'all_remote_tables', 
replicate_insert := true, 
replicate_update := false,
replicate_delete := false,
replicate_truncate := false);
```

Then I added my table:

```
SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_table(
set_name := 'all_remote_tables',
relation := 'measurements',
synchronize_data := true);
```

My subscriber is set up as follows:

```
SELECT pglogical.create_subscription(
subscription_name := 'testsubscription1',
provider_dsn := 'host=$host port=$port dbname=$dbname user=$user password=$pw', 
replication_sets := array['all_remote_tables'],
synchronize_structure := true,
synchronize_data := true,
forward_origins := '{}');
```

With this setup and a table layout like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "measurements"(    
time        TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,   
value       NUMERIC,
sensor_id   TEXT);
```

only the structure is replicated.

As soon as I add a primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE "measurements"(            
id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
time        TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,   
value       NUMERIC,
sensor_id   TEXT);
```

everything is working as expected.

Since I want to store high frequency timeseries (using [timescaledb](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb)) and will never have the need to update/delete single rows I don't see the benefits of a primary key here. Therefore I want to know if pglogical is not working without primary keys by design or if I did some misconfiguration.

The prebuilt replication set "default_insert_only" works without any primary key, but I want to use my own replication sets.

A little offtopic: would you even recommend using pglogical for simple multiple masters > one slave replication of specific tables (= [aggregation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7LOy.png))? Since [postgres 10](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/New_in_postgres_10#Logical_Replication) logical replication is part of the core anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need custom replication set for that, there is preexisting default_insert_only set for this purpose. Check chapter "2.4 Replication Sets" in [pglogical docs](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/pglogical-docs/).

Comment: That's true, I want to have full control over my replication sets, though. The documentation states `The "default_insert_only" only replicates INSERTs and is meant for tables that don't have primary key (see Limitations section for details).` I don't see a difference to my self defined replication set, still it won't work without a primary key.

Comment: The builtin "default_insert_only" replication set works as expected, even without a primary key.